# How do i place a button in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, image, xcode8

I have quite a few labels and buttons on my view controller and I have an image and I have set it to the back in the layers part on the left. How ever when I make it bigger it seems to go to the front and block the images. I have tried multiple codes from other people who have the same problem, but it still doesn't work. I am using Xcode 8, Swift, iOS.

Comment: Are you in interface builder?

Comment: try using [`self.view.sendSubview(toBack:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622618-sendsubview)

Comment: Sweet thanks man, sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In interface builder you can change the order of what is in front or behind by changing the order of the views as they appear in the Document Outline...

[image]

The higher up the list they appear, the further towards the back they are.